# Why pyspark is taking so long to create a SparkSession on jupyter?

Tags: python, windows, session, pyspark

Whell i'm learning PySpark, i installed ipykernel, jupyterlab, notebook and pyspark via PIP, and Java 8 via .exe, the problem is when i need to create the session, like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

takes too long, to the point of not being able to create the session
Any idea of why it happens? I'm on windows!

Comment: how much long? few seconds ? minute ? hour ?

Comment: i left my computer trying yesterday and wasn't possible to create the session

Comment: @Steven How long is it supposed to take? I have the same problem in a JupyterNotebook on my laptop. Does it take 10min? Or more?